# Wordpress Ordering Issues

Tags: php, wordpress

I've got a theme that I'm using and it's throwing posts up on a slider on my home page but I would like to order the way they show up. The code currently in place is:

```
<?php
//OptionTree Stuff
if ( function_exists( 'get_option_tree') ) {
    $theme_options = get_option('option_tree');
    $homeCategory = get_option_tree('home_category',$theme_options);
    $homeNumber = get_option_tree('home_number',$theme_options);
}
?>

    <?php
    $temp = $wp_query;
    $wp_query= null;
    $wp_query = new WP_Query();
    $wp_query->query('cat='. $homeCategory .'&showposts='. $homeNumber .''.'&paged='.$paged);
    while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
    ?>
```

And the way I would like this to be ordered would be the following:

```
orderby=meta_value&meta_key=event_date&order=ASC
```

I've never used option tree before in obtaining information from some theme options, so I'm kind of confused on how I would integrate that ordering method with the other code. Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Jarth

Answer (score 0):

I would need to dig through the documentation for the option tree, but I definitely recommend retrieving the values into variables before you plug them into the query. For example, fist dump the meta value into a variable. Then retrieve the values you want from that array... and so on. At any point you can do a var_dump() to make sure you're getting the expected values.

Once you have that working, you should be able "orderby" the appropriate column.